# Ruby + Sequel + Sinatra + MySQL connection issues

Tags: mysql, ruby, sinatra, sequel

Hi have a simple web app built in ruby, sinatra and sequel connected to a mysql DB. Im using

Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
ruby 2.0.0
gem 'sinatra', '1.4.5'
gem 'slim', '2.0.3'
gem 'sequel', '4.38.0'
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.54, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3

Im having an issue that the app fails  when accessing different parts of the application throwing random errors with status 500 (there is bug, since after trying a few times it works). Im suspecting is a problem with Sequel + Mysql. The app works for a while, then it stops working and then it works again by itself.

I know there is no much description but Im clueless. Any idea?

Comment: Can you provide an example of error your application threw when it stops working? If you think the problem is Sequel + MySQL, please provide more detail about your connection setup (how you connect to MySQL DB using the Sequel ORM).

Comment: I connect using Sequel.connect(DATABASE_URL) where DATABASE_URL=mysql2://<user>:<password>@localhost/<db_name>. The errors I have in the ruby side are random, but it usually refers to an unexpected nil value (something that changes every time)

Comment: Mysql logs says InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
Im using unicorn with NGINX to serve the app with 5 worker_processes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using preload_app in your Unicorn configuration, but aren't disconnecting Sequel's database connections before the fork, that could possibly cause the errors you are seeing.  I think both Sequel's and Unicorn's documentation explain the issue:

https://bogomips.org/unicorn/Unicorn/Configurator.html
http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/code_order_rdoc.html#label-Disconnect+If+Using+Forking+Webserver+with+Code+Preloading